# Is there a way to see all Google Sheets that link/depend on another one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I know what I'm doing is not good, and we're working on changing it for the better, but in the meantime I need to make do with what I have...

I have a rather large Google Sheet that more or less is acting as a DB. It's fed data from GForms and then that data is used on a number of other sheets for various purposes (e.g. reporting, selective info sharing to certain groups, etc.) mostly through `query`s and `importrange`s.

The editing of the main sheet is restricted to only a handful of people, including myself. One of the others has made some changes (deleting some columns) that are going to break any queries or imports because the `importrange` won't catch the column changes and auto-update the range.

The changes made are actually good and worth keeping, so I don't want to revert them.

Is there a way for me to easily find out all of the sheets that use the main one so that I can update the affected formulas? In updating, I'll also need to find a way to avoid this happening again (I think I can do this by setting the range references using `address`? But that's future me's problem...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Find (Ctrl-H) gives the option to "Also search within formulae"

You can use this to search for references to a particular sheet eg searching "sheet1!" will find all cells that reference sheet1

Note this may not work if named ranges are defined, you may need to search for the named range as well.

Answer (score 0):

To find dependencies between sheets in different documents (or even the same document) use the following script to search for references to a given doc id (eg within IMPORTRANGE) eg:

```
FindFormulae("1XgTuET_dJKP-i4JppvQQFI047-ZKP-i4o4bhE-K1lF-o")
```

```
function FindFormulae(keyword) {
// searches all google docs for formulae containing the given keyword
// outputs to sheet "output"
// may take a while if you have a lot of docs, and could timeout (5 minutes)
// if timeout just run the script again, it skips any docs already checked
// to cancel script execution go to https://script.google.com/home/executions
// Feb 2020 www.enex.net 

var sheetOut= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("output");

docsAlreadyChecked = sheetOut.getRange(1,1,sheetOut.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {  // loop thru files
  var file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() != "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") continue;  // only process spreadsheets
  docURL =file.getUrl();
  docName =file.getName();
  //Logger.log('Starting.. ' + docName + '\n' + docURL + '\n');

  //DaysSinceUpdate = (new Date() - file.getLastUpdated())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
  //if ( DaysSinceUpdate > 90 ) continue;  // skip if file hasn't been updated for more than 7 days   

  if (docsAlreadyChecked.toString().indexOf(docName)>0) continue;  // skip if already done    // note this needs fixing as will fail if one doc is substring of another

  var ssIn = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(docURL); // open doc

  for (var i = 0; i < ssIn.getNumSheets(); i++) {  //loop thru sheets in doc
    sheetname = ssIn.getSheets()[i].getName();
    //sheetid = ssIn.getSheets()[i].getSheetId();
    if (ssIn.getSheets()[i].getMaxRows()==0) continue; //skip if no rows (eg if it's a chart)
    ListFormulae(docURL, sheetname, keyword);
  } // end for loop thru sheets

  //strHyperlink = "=hyperlink(\"" + docURL + "#gid=" + ssIn.getSheets()[i].getSheetId() + "\", \"" + docName + "\")";
  strHyperlink = "=hyperlink(\"" + docURL  + "\", \"" + docName + "\")";
  sheetOut.appendRow([strHyperlink, '', '', 'finished search ' + new Date() ]);

} // end while loop thru files

}

function ListFormulae(docURL, sheetname, keyword) {


var ssIn = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(docURL); 
var sheetIn = ssIn.getSheetByName(sheetname);
//var sheetIn = ssIn.getSheetId(sheetid);
//var sheetname = ssIn.getSheetName();
var sheetOut= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("output");
LastRow = sheetIn.getLastRow();
LastColumn = sheetIn.getLastColumn();
if (LastRow==0 && LastColumn==0)  return;  // nothing in sheet 

var range = sheetIn.getRange(1, 1,LastRow , LastColumn);
var formulas = range.getFormulas();
for (var i in formulas) {
  for (var j in formulas[i]) {
    if (formulas[i][j]=="") continue;  // skip if no formula
    if (formulas[i][j].search(keyword) == -1) continue;  //skip if keyword not found
    strHyperlink = "=hyperlink(\"" + docURL + "#gid=" + sheetIn.getSheetId() + "\", \"" + ssIn.getName() + "\")";

    rownum = parseInt(i)+1;
    colnum = parseInt(j)+1;

    sheetOut.appendRow([strHyperlink, sheetname, 'R' + rownum + 'C' + colnum, "'" + formulas[i][j]]);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: If anyone can suggest ways to speed up this script it would be much appreicated. I need to trace a ton of dependencies and whilst this script is far quicker than waiting for someone to report a sheet as broken, it's still a little tedious if you have several hundred sheets! Of course one option is to manually filter the search space, but maybe google offer an array search that's faster than a for loop. Thanks